# Why is opencv dnn blobfromimages working slower than individual images sent through blobfromimage one by one for batch processing?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, batch-processing, object-detection

I am working on sending a batch of images through a CNN using opencv dnn module. I tried using opencv dnn blob from images to process them at once to generate a blob. But it is taking longer than sending each image through the network one by one. Should nt processing a batch of images be faster?

I am just using one for loop to go through the detectons so I know its not that.
 parts is an array of images

```
blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImages(
                parts, 
                1.0,
                (300, 300),
                (104.0, 177.0, 123.0)
            )


self._net.setInput(blob)


detectns = self._net.forward()
```

Batch processing 4 images is taking around 350 ms approx while processing them one by one is around 200 - 250 ms .

Comment: can you explain that cv2.resize(frame, (300, 300)) call there? Imho you should provide a target size and not a resized image there?!?

Comment: Sorry that is  commented out. My bad. I am passing parts which is an array of images.